# programming for sound design and music

Tags: sound-design, audio, software, hardware, programming

Does someone have any names of softwares/gears related to sound that allow scripting or/and programming.

my list for the moment:

*Software - Language - Purpose:*

**Ableton Live** - ClyphX, Max/MSP - Clip management, A lot of possibilities

**Lemur** - Scripting Language - MIDI/OSC controllers

**Bitwig** - (javascript) - Controllers Customisation

**Sony Sound Forge** - C# - Scripting, bulk tasks

**Reaper, ReaJS** - Jesusonic - Scripting Language for real-time audio and midi processing

**FMOD** - Many laguages -  Audio Engine for video games

**Pure Data** - Pure Data - graphic language for multimedia purposes

... Any Others?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: www.fmod.org ? https://www.audiokinetic.com/products/wwise/ ? http://puredata.info/ ? Your question is not very clear as it is. Feel free to improve it.

Comment: Would the C# scripting in Sony's Sound Forge apply? It's quite versatile. @audionuma - nice links.

Comment: Cockos (who also make Reaper) develops the jesusonic scripting language for real-time audio and midi processing.

Comment: Do check out TidalCycles and ORCA, you can develop a lot of crazy stuff in the world of algorave :)

Answer (score 1):

[Sonic Pi](https://sonic-pi.net/) is an easy to use, open source language for programming synthesizers and more. It can be used with pretty much an OS. I use it for Raspberry Pi.

EDIT: I highly recommend taking a look at the source code. I've built multiple projects for Raspberry Pi.

Although not a programming language, I would also recommend [VCV Rack](https://github.com/VCVRack/Rack) for learning how to build your own modular synthesizers. It's also open source, so you can progtam your own eurorack modules.